# AVAudioPlayer continues to play after segue and relaunches on return to original view controller - how can I stop it?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a strange little problem with an `AVAudioPlayer` that I can't find a nice tidy solution to. I'm using the following function to play some background music in the menu screen of my app:

```
func startMusic() {
    do {
        try musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("menu_music", ofType: "mp3")!))
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print (err.debugDescription)
    }       
    musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    musicPlayer.play()
}
```

I call it in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        startMusic()        
    }
```

So far so good.

The menu has several buttons which take the user to other screens via segues that have all been created in interface builder - no programmatic segues.

The first issue is that the music carries on playing when the other screens are loaded. This is actually a nice, desirable effect in most cases, but I'd like to know if there is a way of stopping it other than creating menu button actions that include `musicPlayer.stop()` or `musicPlayer.pause()`. For instance, can one view controller stop an `AVAudioPlayer` that was started in another?

The more serious problem that I am having is that when I navigate back to the menu screen (again, via a button that launches an interface builder created segue), a duplicate copy of the music starts to play over the original (sounds horrible) and there doesn't seem to be any way to stop it or check if it is playing. If more menu options are clicked and then returned from, yet MORE copies of the music start playing.

I've tried

```
if (!musicPlayer.playing) { 
    musicPlayer.play() 
}
```

and

```
if (musicPlayer == nil) { 
    musicPlayer.play() 
}
```

as well as stopping and starting the player each time, but I still get multiple copies of the same music playing over each other. It's as if there are multiple music players with the same name which can't be stopped or multiple copies of the same view controller running in the background.

I realize that I am probably missing something absolutely fundamental here, but Googling has failed to provide me with an answer and I know that the good people of Stack Overflow won't let me down.

Thanks.

Comment: `if (musicPlayer == nil)`, if your `musicPlayer` is `nil` you'd probably want to recreate it. Perhaps you meant `if (musicPlayer != nil)`?

Comment: Sorry, no. What I'm trying to do is only start the music if it isn't already playing.

Comment: Your `if (!musicPlayer.playing)` should accomplish that. Is there anywhere else you're creating your `AVAudioPlayer`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't work. And no, the only place that `musicPlayer` is created is in the function shown above. On return to the menu view controller, the already playing version can't be stopped or checked for `.playing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out...

It's to do with the way I built the segues in interface builder (which was probably wrong all along). If you ctrl-drag from a button to a view controller to create a segue and then do the same (ctrl-drag from a button back to the first view controller) to create the 'back' segue, then this appears to create multiple instances of the AVAudioPlayer (or possibly the whole menu view controller) and this creates the nasty effect caused by multiple version of the music playing over each other.

**HOWEVER** If you use an *UNWIND* segue to get back to the menu then the music plays throughout, but doesn't start again on return to the menu. Tidy.

In order to stop the music for the menu choices where it is necessary to stop it, the only way seems to be with an action that stops the music and then calls the segue programmatically.

Creating all the segues in interface builder is quick and easy, but there are clearly cases when lines of code will always be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In your main view controller's `viewWillDisappear` you can `stop` your `AVAudioPlayer`.

For example:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    musicPlayer.stop()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. This stops the music for any menu choice, but do you know of a way to allow it to carry on playing while the secondary screen is visible without the player starting a duplicate on return to the menu?